# How to check if a user is at the checkout page in Prestashop

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I want to check if the user is at the checkout page so I have tried following:

```
{if $page_name = 'cart'}
...
{/if}
```

And in addition to "cart", I have also tried "checkout", "order" etc.

Obviously it didn't work.

I'm trying to edit header.tpl and for the record I'm using one page checkout.

Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Change '=' to '=='

```
{if $page_name == 'order'}
...
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
{if $page_name == 'order-opc'}
```

should get you the one page checkout page.

*edited answer to correct `=` to `==` , sorry about that...

Comment: I have the same issue and this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

For others who are looking for answers for this problem

You can write below code in `header.phtml` file

```
{if $page_name != 'order'}

    <!-- your output -->

                {/if}
```

Comment: Why should we "write below code in..."? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

My working solution at prestashop 1.7.2.0 for cart page

Go to \controllers\front\CartController.php

and find there code

```
if (count($presented_cart['products']) > 0) {
    $this->setTemplate('checkout/cart');
} else {
    $this->context->smarty->assign([
        'allProductsLink' => $this->context->link->getCategoryLink(Configuration::get('PS_HOME_CATEGORY')),
    ]);
    $this->setTemplate('checkout/cart-empty');
}
```

add line ($this->context->smarty->assign(['cart_detect' => 1]);) like below:

```
if (count($presented_cart['products']) > 0) {
    $this->setTemplate('checkout/cart');
    $this->context->smarty->assign(['cart_detect' => 1]);
} else {
    $this->context->smarty->assign([
        'allProductsLink' => $this->context->link->getCategoryLink(Configuration::get('PS_HOME_CATEGORY')),
    ]);
    $this->setTemplate('checkout/cart-empty');
}
```

in your template you can use new variable "cart_detect" like below:

```
{if !isset($cart_detect)}

     {*if not a cart*}

{/if}
```